# How to select an option via python selenium in hidden class?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

I am parsing a website using Selenium.

I need to select an option in hidden class. Html code of this part:

```html
                                    <div class="search region">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="cec-select">
                                                <select tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible"
                                                        aria-hidden="true"><option></option><option value="value_1">text_1</option><option value="value_2">text_2</option></select>
                                                <script>$(function () {
                                                        $('.cec-select select').select2({
                                                            placeholder: "Выберите субъект",
                                                            "language": {
                                                                "noMatches": function () {
                                                                    return "Select a subject";
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }).change(function () {
                                                            window.open($(this).val(), '_blank');
                                                        });
                                                    });</script>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

I tried to select an option as usual via Select function:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('url')

regions = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name("select2-hidden-accessible"))
regions.select_by_index('2')
```

And I got this error message: *ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulate.*

Full error message:

```
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-7e06e646520e> in <module>
----> 1 regions.select_by_index('2')
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py in select_by_index(self, index)
     99         for opt in self.options:
    100             if opt.get_attribute("index") == match:
--> 101                 self._setSelected(opt)
    102                 return
    103         raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with index %d" % index)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py in _setSelected(self, option)
    210     def _setSelected(self, option):
    211         if not option.is_selected():
--> 212             option.click()
    213 
    214     def _unsetSelected(self, option):
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in click(self)
     78     def click(self):
     79         """Clicks the element."""
---> 80         self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
     81 
     82     def submit(self):
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

I guess, I should run a script under options first, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: Corrected my question.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this problem. First, I clicked on text field, so all options became visible on the cite.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Выберите субъект')]")[2].click()
```

[Before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0KZh.png)
[After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13bBk.png)

In html code options are still in the hidden class and I still cannot select them. But I noticed that some new html code appeared after I clicked text field. This new fragment duplicates all options I need. They are now in li tags.

```html
<iframe aria-hidden="true" frameborder="0" name="ym-native-frame" style="opacity: 0 !important; width: 0px !important; height: 0px !important; position: absolute !important; left: 100% !important; bottom: 100% !important; border: 0px !important;" title="ym-native-frame"></iframe><ym-measure class="ym-viewport" style="display: block; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; position: fixed; transform: translate(0px, -100%); transform-origin: 0px 0px;"></ym-measure><ym-measure class="ym-zoom" style="bottom: 100%; position: fixed; width: 100vw;"></ym-measure><span class="select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open" style="position: absolute; top: 1416.33px; left: 844.99px;"><span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 350px;"><span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown"><input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="select2-search__field" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" type="search"/></span><span class="select2-results"><ul aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" class="select2-results__options" id="select2-42bc-results" role="tree"><li aria-selected="false" class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="id_1" role="treeitem">text_1</li><li aria-selected="false" class="select2-results__option" id="id_2" role="treeitem">text_2</li></ul></span></span></span></body></html>
```

So, I accessed li elements with the following code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("select2-results__option")[id].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. `findElementsByXpath` & `findElementByXpath` will need implementations. Note that this code is in Java.

```java
public void selectFromDropdown(){

// Find the size of dropdown list items.

List <WebElement> dropdownSize = findElementsByXpath(".//select[@class='select2-hidden-accessible']//option");

// Iterate thru each dropdown value and click each of them.

if(dropdownSize.size() > 0){
    for(int i=1; i<= dropdownSize.size(); i++){
        findElementByXpath(".//select[@class='select2-hidden-accessible']")
        findElementByXpath(".//select[@class='select2-hidden-accessible']//option["+i+"]").click();
        }
    }
}
```

You can further improve it by adding try/catch and to break out of the loop after selecting a specific value from the dropdown.

Comment: I tried this method. Unfortunately, got the same mistake.